# How to disable bitcode in Xamarin iOS Project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I tried disabling bitcode in xamarin project using `MtouchEnableBitcode` variable as `False` in iOS csproj file. Still i am getting frameworks are not built with bitcode enabled errors while doing app store submission.

Anyone know how to disable bitcode in Xamarin iOS project?

Comment: You are disabling bitcode and get a not enabled error. What is the problem? If app store requires it then enable it

Comment: @svn The third-party frameworks which i am using in the application is not bitcode enabled. Hence i want to disable bitcode feature in application else its throwing me frameworks are not built with bitcode enabled errors during store submission.

Comment: @VittalPai If you are submitting an app for Watch or TV, bitcode is required, if you are submitting for iOS, review your app and each of your included frameworks to determine which one contains bitcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this answer from Microsoft Support. Now i am able to build the application with bitcode disabled by adding following lines to the iOS app project's .csproj file immediately before the closing `</Project>` tag.

```
<Target Name="BeforeCodesign">
  <Exec Command="$(_SdkDevPath)\Toolchains\XcodeDefault.xctoolchain\usr\bin\bitcode_strip %(_Frameworks.FullPath) -r -o %(_Frameworks.FullPath)" />
</Target>
```